# How to use a custom decorator with default Django auth login view

Tags: python, django, authentication, decorator

I am using the default Django authentication system. In my urls, I have :

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Now I have a custom decorator that I want to apply on the login view, similar to how I have applied it on signup.

```
@example_decorator
def signup(request):
     ...
```

But the problem is that I am using default Login View.
Is there any way to apply this decorator to the default Auth View?

I think that I need to extend the default view but I can't find any example to do so. How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can insert your decorated view before your `include` and get desired behaviour.

```
from django.contrib.auth import auth_views

from your_app import example_decorator

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('login/', example_decorator(auth_views.LoginView.as_view()), name='login'),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Comment: @Apaar glad that helped!

Answer (score 1):

If by default login view you mean the login system, the login function; you can indeed decorate it simply with:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

def decorator(f):
    pass

login = decorator(login)

def my_view(request):
    login()
```

Otherwise if you are talking about a clasview just comment so I can explain it as well.

------- Class Based View --------

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

def decorator(f):
    #your decorator

@method_decorator(decorator, name='dispatch')
class MyClass(LoginView):
    pass
```

As far as the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-in-urlconf) go, this should do the trick; although you have to have to write this url yourself, you cannot simply include the auth.urls I'm afraid. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am talking about the class view. Not the login function. Basically I am directly using django.contrib.auth.urls which use the LoginView defined in django.contrib.auth.views. I want to just add the decorator and keep rest of the functionality intact.